# How the noise in time series can be reduced?

Tags: computer-vision, noise, time-series

I have asked the question in the following link: [Are time series data always contain noise?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28367/are-time-series-data-always-contain-noise)
I wonder if we could use variational methods to denoise the time series data just as in computer vision? 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Yes indeed, there is a huge body of works on the topic of variational methods for signal restoration (more general than denoising), one example being [total variation denoising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising#Mathematical_exposition_for_1D_digital_signals), or [proximal methods](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3522).

If you can be more specific, you could get more accurate and precise answers.